# JSHint referencing an outer scope

Tags: javascript, jshint

Hi I have problem with JSHint, cause always getting

> Functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics. ($, totals). 
>   My function call is

```
var a;
a.each(function (c) {
    if (c.length == 0) return;
    for (var index in c) {
        var test = {};

        a.each(function (e) {
            var idx = $(e).data('index');
            if (idx in test) {
                test[idx] += $(e).data('key');
            } else {
                test[idx] = $(e).data('key');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I know that problem because I accessing test variable in the callback, but is there a solution for this, something to rewrite code or to tell JSHint to not throw warning

Comment: You can always disable this rule in general or just for this section of the code.

Comment: I don't think JSHint issues that warning for the code you've quoted (and the live feature on its website confirms that). Perhaps if it's within some other code (in particular, a loop), but not on its own. You're not declaring a function in a loop in that code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, i changed function

Answer (score 0):

*may* should rather be *rarely* or *theoretically*. In most cases (like this one) this hint isn't useful at all and can safely be ignored (or disabled).

The rare case is something like this:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // loop
   setTimeout(function() { // callback
      console.log(i); // outer reference
   }, 100);
}
```

and JSHint tries to warn you in this case, but the scenario that triggers the warning for this reasonable case, occurs very often, and then the warning isn't useful at all (as with jQuery's global).

Comment: "Rare" as in it happens so often we're constantly pointing people at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) and its answers.

Comment: That said, the code in the question doesn't cause the warning (not in isolation), so it's hard to say whether it's a problematic case or one that's fine.

Comment: @t.j. in the last days I've seen at least 3 question asking for this hint with a scenario that is not an async closure inside a for loop.

Comment: I'm just disappointed that it still raises the warning when the variable being used in the function is declared with `let`in the same scope as the function being created. :-| It should be smart enough to know that's not going to cause the problem it warns about. (I suppose I could do a PR, but it's not a tool I use and I'm pretty stacked up with things to do, so...)

Comment: @t.j.crowder exactly, as one can see in this case the warning is missleading and warns in the wrong cases. (same here)

Comment: (Guilt. I'm what's wrong with open source. "It should..." "...but I don't have time..." :-D )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edit function to throw warning in isolation

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for a while, either Internet Explorer or Microsoft Edge supported `let` syntax and implemented it with `var` semantics. I forget which one it was, but maybe that's why the warning still applies to `let`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - It was IE9+ (yes, including IE11). And that's a **very** good point. Really looking forward to IE finally being completely irrelevant in a few years (and Edge switching to Chromium and V8).